# Value not stored in list of list in recursive call

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist, backtracking

The below is my recursive function. I'm trying to learn backtracking in Java. In the res object, I add the list object, but when returned from the function the res is empty, whereas I try to print the list object when I'm adding in res it shows values. k variable is greater than zero.

```
    void help(int arr[],int k,int i,int n,List<Integer> list,List<List<Integer>> res){
    if(list.size()==k){
        res.add(list);        
        System.out.println(list);
        return;
    }
    for(int j=i;j<arr.length;j++){
        list.add(arr[j]);
        help(arr,k,i+1,n,list,res);
       list.remove(new Integer(arr[j]));
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Replacing res.add(list) from res.add(new ArrayList<>(list)) works for me. But i am still unclear why i nedd to create new arrayList object each time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the order of operations. I've added numbers on the side to explain.

```
void help(int arr[],int k,int i,int n,List<Integer> list,List<List<Integer>> res){
    if(list.size()==k){
        res.add(list);        
        System.out.println(list);        // 2
        return;                          // 3 
    }
    for(int j=i;j<arr.length;j++){
        list.add(arr[j]);
        help(arr,k,i+1,n,list,res);      // 1
       list.remove(new Integer(arr[j])); // 4
    }
    
}
```

When you issue a recursive call to `help` in 1, it will start a recursive call. If you reach the base case in 2 and 3, you **will print** a result. However, then you are **back to 4** to finish the recursive call chain, which will begin removing elements from the list.
This means that you are **printing intermediate results** and there are operations that follow after that, specifically call 4, and at the end of the recursion your **list is empty**. That is where the problem is.

Comment: But when i met the base condition 3,4 I have already added my list object to res object and in 2  i am just removing from the list object not from the res so why res shows empty.

Comment: You are adding the reference to `list` into `res`. You are not doing `res.add(new ArrayList<>(list))` for example. That's why `res` just holds a reference to `list` which gets modified, so you are not seeing any data in `res` as a result.